# Java passing object as argument

Tags: java, pointers

In java , let's say I have a reference to an object , and a function:

```
object p = new object();
function(p);
```

where function is:

```
public void function(object x)
{
///
}
```

What actually happens in memory here?I think of x and p as pointers in C++.Will "x" and "p" have the same value,but different adresses in memory , or they will have the same value and adress?Thanks.

Comment: java is "passed by value of the reference". once you understand that, things are easy. and this is a duplicate anyway

Comment: Does [Is Java pass by reference or pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) answer your question?